# Recording the byte size of an HTTP request in JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, node.js, http

With Node.js, how can I see the size in bytes of a simple HTTP data transfer?

For example, I'm sending a simple JSON string. I want the size of the message body.

Can I save the string to a .txt for an accurate representation of its byte size?

Comment: As a server or as a client?

Comment: Server. Through Node. @TimWolla

Comment: Which size exactly? The size of the body or the size of the complete request?

Comment: if its just the response body, count the stringified json length , plus some bytes that are added by default to response.

Comment: I could be missing something, but you have to send the request body string somewhere. So its `.length`?

Comment: @Phoenix You make it sound as if each character of the stringified json is 1 byte.. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`Buffer.byteLength`](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_bytelength_string_encoding):

```
console.log('☺'.length); // 1 char
console.log(Buffer.byteLength('☺')); // 3 bytes
```